# Control algorithms for drones

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller

I am hobbyist trying to understand control architecture of quadcopter.Cascaded control helps rejecting any disturbances, giving a fast response. But then why are using a square root controller instead of P controller, which makes my system slower. I have read papers on gain scheduling, but still don't get the intution. Any explanation resources, to help me understand better, will be useful.
[image]

Comment: Hi! You should probably clarify which flight controller software you are talking about. Based on your image, I assume that it is ArduCopter, as I found the same image here: https://nrotella.github.io/journal/arducopter-flight-controllers.html, but we will be able to help you more effectively if you add that to your question.